# Oracle JDBC driver upward compatibility

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

We use Oracle JDBC Driver 9.2.0 with Oracle 11g and we have problems like hotspot errors etc. Do you think JDBC drivers are upward compatible? Unfortunately I could not find any compatibility matrix for these versions

Thanks
Zoltan

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02

Comment: The 9.2.0 driver must be 10 years old by now, why not just upgrade to a newer driver?

Comment: In my experience the 9.x drivers were all pretty buggy and slow. Since 10.x (even more so with 11.x) the driver became *much* better. And as a general rule of thumb the driver version should match the database version.

Comment: We had these problems as well. It seems that there were some major changes from oracle 9-10-11 I would strongly advise ensuring your db driver is the same as the db. Oracle is usually very good at backwards compatibility but we also issues with the 11 driver accessing a 9 db

Comment: #Mark - we would like to upgrade, but now we just want to know whether using version can cause problems we have or not